# Is there any downside to a huge swap partition?

Tags: swap

After adding a larger boot drive to my server, I've got a spare 250 GB LVM partition available.  Is there any downside to using this as-is for swap space on a server with 4GB of physical RAM?  I don't expect it would see much use, as the server normally sits around 10% of RAM used, with the other 90% being disk cache.

Answer (score 1):

Just imagine how long will it take to read from swap to memory 250GB :) Such huge swap is useless. In practice, you generally do not want to be swapped out more than 0.5-1Gb of memory. The only case, where you'll need a large swap – hybernate. But you need no more, than your memory size.

You can create filesystem on your LV and mkswap a 4GB-file on it. It will fit you perfectly. Another 246Gb could be used for backup, for example, or something else.